# Como recuperar o address da função que carregaou minha dll ou o PE da thread onde foi carregada

Tags: c

A thread que carrega a minha DLL usa LoadlibraryA , eu gostaria de recuperar o address (01145EA7)  da instrução que carrega ela ou o PE (01C5B514) da thread que carrega ela.

```
load dll assm:

01145EA2  PUSH 01FDE6B8                             ; /FileName = "psHook.dll"
01145EA7  CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.LoadLibrar> ; \LoadLibraryA
01145EAD  MOV DWORD PTR DS:[230E970],EAX

PE assm:
01C5B514 CALL 01C5BA38



My DLL:

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    (VOID)hInstDLL;
    (VOID)lpvReserved;

    switch(fdwReason)
    {
            case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            hook_func();
            (CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&UsedTimer,0,0,NULL));
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            FreeLibrary(hInstDLL);
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

uso GetMainThreadId() para recupear o IP da thread que eu quero recuperar o PE ou o Address base.

```
DWORD GetMainThreadId() {
    HANDLE  hThreadSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);

    if (hThreadSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        WriteInConsole("Falha ao criar snapshot");
    }

    THREADENTRY32 tEntry;
    tEntry.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);
    DWORD result = 0;
    DWORD currentPID = GetCurrentProcessId();
    for (BOOL success = Thread32First(hThreadSnapshot, &tEntry);
        !result && success && GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES;
        success = Thread32Next(hThreadSnapshot, &tEntry))
    {
        if (tEntry.th32OwnerProcessID == currentPID) {
            result = tEntry.th32ThreadID;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Isso é assembly?

Comment: A DLL esta em C, o codigo ao qual voce se refere sim, a solução esta logo abaixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução GetModuleInformation retorna um objeto com as informações(PE,BaseAddr, Size) de um modulo, entao basta calcular a diferença entre o Address e o AddressBase;

```
#include "wFunc.h"
#include "wAddr.h"
#include "wInline.h"
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>

DWORD GetMainThreadId() {
    HANDLE  hThreadSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);

    if (hThreadSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        WriteInConsole("Falha ao criar snapshot");
    }

    THREADENTRY32 tEntry;
    tEntry.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);
    DWORD result = 0;
    DWORD currentPID = GetCurrentProcessId();
    for (BOOL success = Thread32First(hThreadSnapshot, &tEntry);
        !result && success && GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES;
        success = Thread32Next(hThreadSnapshot, &tEntry))
    {
        if (tEntry.th32OwnerProcessID == currentPID) {
            result = tEntry.th32ThreadID;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
MODULEINFO GetModuleInfo(char* szModule)
{
    MODULEINFO modinfo = { 0 };
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(szModule);
    if (hModule == 0) return modinfo;
    GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess() /*Internal*/, hModule, &modinfo, sizeof(MODULEINFO));
    return modinfo;
}



BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{

    (VOID)hInstDLL;
    (VOID)lpvReserved;
    WriteInConsole("PID: %p \n", GetMainThreadId());

    TCHAR szName[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleBaseName(GetCurrentProcess(), GetModuleHandle(NULL), szName, MAX_PATH);
    WriteInConsole("Handle Name: %s \n\n", szName);

    MODULEINFO mod_Client = GetModuleInfo(szName);

    MainBaseAddr    = mod_Client.lpBaseOfDll;
    MainSizeAddr    = mod_Client.SizeOfImage;
    MainPE          = mod_Client.EntryPoint;

    WriteInConsole("PE: %p \n", MainPE);
    WriteInConsole("BASE ADDRESS: %p \n", MainBaseAddr);
    WriteInConsole("SIZE: %p \n\n", MainSizeAddr);

    WriteInConsole("Called on BETs: %p \n", (((DWORD)MainBaseAddr) + ((DWORD)0x008E8C40)));

    switch(fdwReason)
    {
            case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            hook_func();
            //(CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&UsedTimer,0,0,NULL));
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            FreeLibrary(hInstDLL);
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```